Cannot import tensorflow_hub after install tensorflow_text. Cannot use BERT with tensorflow hub
I use pip to install tensorflow_text on google colab. After I finish install, google colab told me I had to restart the session and I did it. After that, I import tensorflow_hub and get this error.
!pip install tensorflow_text

import tensorflow_text as text
import tensorflow_hub as hub

preprocessor = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4")

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-28997455fe8d> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 import tensorflow_text as text
----> 4 import tensorflow_hub as hub
      5 
      6 preprocessor = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_keras/src/saving/legacy/saved_model/load_context.py in <module>
     66 
     67 
---> 68 tf.__internal__.register_load_context_function(in_load_context)
     69 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'```


If I don't install tensorflow_text, I cannot use Bert preprocessor and encoder from tensorflow hub. If I install tensorflow_text, I cannot import tensorflow_hub so I cannot use BERT preprocessor and bert_encoder too. Are there any others way to use BERT with tensorflow?
